# Multiplying an integer by a float literal - is the "F" required?

Tags: c

Is this:

```
int i = 100 * 0.6;
```

less correct than this?

```
int i = 100 * (0.6F);
```

I apologize for such a simple question, but I haven't memorized all the rules for data type promotions and I'm not really sure how to even verify this.

Comment: The parentheses are definitely not required and do look strange. 0.6F is a token.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can make a difference.  For [**example**](http://ideone.com/JXIT2V):

```
int i = (1 << 24) + 3;

printf("%d\n", (int)(i * 0.6));    // 10066331
printf("%d\n", (int)(i * 0.6f));   // 10066332
```

The reason is that the calculation for the first is done in double-precision, the latter in single-precision.  Single-precision cannot represent all integers greater than `1 << 24`.

Another [**example**](http://ideone.com/hnl7tr) (courtesy of @EricPostpischil in the comments below):

```
int i = 100;

printf("%d\n", (int)(i * 0.29));    // 28
printf("%d\n", (int)(i * 0.29f));   // 29
```

Here the reason is that the intermediate result in the double-precision case falls slightly below 29, and so is truncated down to 28.

So I would suggest allowing double-precision (i.e. omitting the `f`/`F`) (and then using `round()` rather than relying on implicit truncation) unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: A smaller example, and a case where using `double` leads to a less accurate result, is that `int i = 100 * .29f;` produces 29 while `int i = 100 * .29;` produces 28 (using IEEE-754 binary floating-point).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Oh that's interesting.  Why the discrepancy there?  Neither single nor double can exactly represent 0.29; does one quantize up and the other down?

Comment: +1 , but a question:  Is not the compiler _allowed_, though not _required_, to do the calculation in higher precision math?  Thus the answer could be the same?

Comment: @chux: That's an interesting question, and my answer is "I don't know!".  I imagine Eric can give you a better answer ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: There are cases where `float` rounds a value down and `double` rounds it up, but this one is even more interesting. Both round .29 down in this case. But multiplying by 100 rounds up to 29 in `float` while the more accurate `double` remains less than 29.

Comment: @chux: True. "The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be
represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not
changed thereby." ISO/IEC 9899:1999 6.3.1.8.

Comment: @chux: Yes, a compiler can use more precision. In this case, that could be worse, because it could make the `float` case wrong.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil  I started noticing things like this with a recent compiler that does most FP math with `long double`.

Answer (score 5):

The `F` is not required in this particular case.  All it does is specify the constant as being of type `float` instead of type `double`.

Answer (score 1):

The first says, and reduces to

```
i [int] = 100 [int] * 0.6 [double]
i [int] = 100.0 [double] * 0.6 [double]
i [int] = 60.0 [double]
```

The second says

```
i [int] = 100 [int] * 0.6 [float]
i [int] = 100.0 [float] * 0.6 [float]
i [int] = 60.0 [float]
```

Both are effectively the same, unless you specifically care about float vs. double precision.

Answer (score 1):

On embedded systems, the difference may be significant besides in precision also in execution time. f suffix makes the number a floating point constant as opposed to double precision floating point constant as others have already noted.

If all operands are floats the math operation will happen using single precision floating point. If the processor has a single precision floating point unit, the calculations may use it (depending on compiler options).

If on the other hand *any* operand is a double, the calculation happens in double precision. If the cpu has only single precision FPU, it means that the calculation will be done using a SW library. The execution time of the code in question in that case will be several times longer.

Example of such CPU is ARM Cortex-M4F.

Similar but not so radical difference effect is in the case of no FPU. All floating point operations use sw library. Double precision will take more time.

Comment: +1 For embedded considerations.  In a embedded environment I used, float and double were that same, hence `double` took the same time as `float`.